# vtkResliceImageViewer get bounds image in view

Tags: c++, vtk

**Situation:**
I'm using vtkresliceimageviewer to display the three MPR views, based on this example.

So I can rotate the cursors to generate a new view on all three screens.

**Question:**
I want to know the bounds of my image on the viewer, even after rotating some of the cursors.

**obs**
I tried to get the values from the imageActor and ask for my renderer positions, but this works only when I have no interaction from the other cursors.
Example for axial:

```
void UpdatePointWordToViewer(vtkRenderer* rend, double p[4])
{
    rend->SetWorldPoint(p);
    rend->WorldToDisplay();
    rend->GetDisplayPoint(p);
}

void UpdateBoxAxial()
{
    auto bounds = pMPR->GetViewer(2)->GetImageActor()->GetBounds();
    auto ren = pMPR->GetViewer(2)->GetRenderer();
    auto size = pMPR->GetViewer(2)->GetInteractor()->GetSize();

    double pIni1[]{ 0,0,0,1 };
    double pIni2[]{ 0,0,0,1 };
    double pIni3[]{ 0,0,0,1 };
    double pIni4[]{ 0,0,0,1 };
    double pConvert1[]{ 0,0,0 };
    double pConvert2[]{ 0,0,0 };

    //check the bounds
    pIni1[0] = bounds[0];
    pIni1[1] = bounds[3];
    pIni1[2] = bounds[4];

    pIni2[0] = bounds[1];
    pIni2[1] = bounds[3];
    pIni2[2] = bounds[4];

    pIni3[0] = bounds[0];
    pIni3[1] = bounds[2];
    pIni3[2] = bounds[4];

    pIni4[0] = bounds[1];
    pIni4[1] = bounds[2];
    pIni4[2] = bounds[4];

    //convert the points for viewer coordinates
    UpdatePointWordToViewer(ren, pIni1);
    UpdatePointWordToViewer(ren, pIni2);
    UpdatePointWordToViewer(ren, pIni3);
    UpdatePointWordToViewer(ren, pIni4);

    //P1
    if (pIni1[0] < pIni3[0])
        pConvert1[0] = pIni1[0];
    else
        pConvert1[0] = pIni3[0];

    if (pIni3[1] < pIni4[1])
        pConvert1[1] = pIni3[1];
    else
        pConvert1[1] = pIni4[1];

    //P2
    if (pIni2[0] > pIni4[0])
        pConvert2[0] = pIni2[0];
    else
        pConvert2[0] = pIni4[0];

    if (pIni1[1] > pIni2[1])
        pConvert2[1] = pIni1[1];
    else
        pConvert2[1] = pIni2[1];
}
```

So I know the minimum point (Left - Down) and the maximum point (Right - Top)